# Do AJAX requests sent from the background page of Chrome Extension send a referrer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm curious whether or not AJAX requests sent from the background page of my Chrome Extension will send referrer information? Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "requests sent from the background page" what does this mean??

Comment: I mean AJAX requests, aka XMLHTTPRequests...

Comment: If u mean u r sending ajax request to server on page load or dom ready automatically, then yes referrer information will  be send, why do u think it wouldn't!!

Comment: Because this is a CHROME EXTENSION, and likely things work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified one of my own Chrome extensions to use jQuery's .ajax call. When the call goes out I see with fiddler that no referer information is included by default. One thing you could try though would be to explicitly set the referer value for your ajax request. If you come up with a code example (not sure how to do it myself) I can try that out for you.

Comment: Thanks, I found a webpage on the internet that would give a response containing all header information ;)

Answer (score 3):

No it will not. Background pages do not redirect so there is no referrer to send. Just the origin.